# Buscar datos sin recargar la página

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp

Quisiera realizar una búsqueda de datos por cierto patrón, resumiéndolo, estoy intentando buscar los datos de cierto DNI como se muestra en el código y que se impregne en los otros input (menos en los *combobx*). Todo esto quisiera realizarlo mediante un botón, ya aplique *ajax* con función pero nada de nada, amablemente pido si es que me pueden ayudar, no pido el código ,si no la lógica de cómo se podría hacer ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento con *ajax*, sé lo basico.

```html
<body>
<h1 align="center">Ingrese sus Datos</h1>
<br><br>
<form action="ControladorDatos" method="post" >
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td> Recuperar accesos: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="codtip" class="custom-select" required>
                    <option disabled selected value="">Seleccione Solicitud</option>
                    <%  
                    List<ClassTipo> listadotip = cbitip.listadoTipo();
                        for(ClassTipo tip: listadotip){%>
                        <option value="<%=tip.getCodigoTipo() %>"><%=tip.getNomTipo() %></option>
                        <%} %>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DNI:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="dniu" type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" required> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <abbr title="Digita tu dni y dale clic a la lupa del costado" style="margin-left: 15px"> 
                    <img src="Imagenes/busqueda.png" width="30px" height="30px">                    
                </abbr>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="obtenerDatosDNI()">Buscar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Codigo de Ingresate:</td><td><input id="ingresante" type="text" name="codingre" 
                                                    class="form-control" required >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Apellido Paterno:</td>
            <td><input id="paterno" type="text" name="apepater"     
                                                 class="form-control" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Apellido Materno:</td>
            <td><input id="materno" type="text" name="apemater"         
                                                 class="form-control" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombres: </td>
            <td><input id="nombre" type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" 
                                         required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Programa:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="codprog" class="custom-select" required>
                    <option disabled selected value="">Seleccione Programa</option>
                    <%
                    List<ClassPrograma> listadoprog = cbitip.listadoPrograma();
                        for(ClassPrograma p:listadoprog){%>
                        <option value="<%=p.getCodPrograma()%>"><%=p.getNomPorgrama()%></option>
                        <%}; %>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Correo Institucional:</td>
            <td><input id="institucional" type="text" 
                                                     name="corinsti" 
                                                     class="form-control" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Correo Personal:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="corperso" class="form-control" 
                                                required>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr align="center"><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Gestionar 
                                                                 Reseteo" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```